# Does CiviCRM work with WP Engine after August's update?

Tags: wordpress

I work at WP Engine and we have a customer who was running CiviCRM with us.  They recently ran an update for the 5.52 release and the plugin is no longer working with us.  Is there a way to offload cache files to another directory or handle temporary files?  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to 'move' the template directory following the convention here - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template#L166  in the `civicrm.settings.php` file that is by default located in the wp upload directory and subdirectory civicrm.

Comment: Hey Kevin!  We've tried this with their staging site and it's still not working. See here: https://applebaumphstg.wpengine.com/wp-admin/
It's trying to put the files in a different folder than /uploads/ but it's not working there either(or generally any other directory I've tried).

Comment: In the past I've had issues with WPE's NAS setup - we actually have a patch to try and handle this.  Can you detail the directories you are using and what gets set.

Comment: @Matt were you able to resolve this issue? I have a client about to commit to WP Engine and I would like to know if it is a good option.